# Can somebody explain "$40 per share of a $110 stock" for me, please?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Repatriation of the dollar. Apple has a mountain of cash overseas which it hasn't been able to bring back to the U.S. because it would be hit with a 40 percent tax rate. As of the end of September, Apple had $237 billion in cash and marketable securities, and 91 percent of that was outside the U.S., which amounts to roughly $216 billion, or **$40 per share of a $110 stock**.

source: [www.cnbc.com](http://www.cnbc.com/2016/11/18/cramers-2-reasons-why-Trump-could-save-Apple-billions.html)

Comment: The reporter meant to write **overseas** not "oversees". If the money held overseas is allowed to be "repatriated" at a zero tax rate, and if those tax savings were returned to shareholders as a dividend, it would amount to $40 per share on a stock whose share price is now $110.

Answer (score 1):

It means that out of a [market capitalization](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/m/marketcapitalization.asp) of  $110  per share, $40  are represented by the $216 billions  cash held abroad.

It turns out that  the  net financial valuation of the business part of the company is $70 per share.

From: Investopedia

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably better asked on https://money.stackexchange.com/, because to understand the text one needs some basic finance knowledge.

One way to measure the value of a company is by multiplying number of shares outstanding and the amount of money each share is worth. At the time the author wrote the question, there are 5.4 billion shares outstanding for Apple. The price per share is $110. Using the above, at that moment in time Apple is worth 5.4 billion * $110 = $594 billion in total.

We know the value of $216 billion in cash and marketable securities, and that obviously is $216 billion. One way to measure the value of a company is the amount of cash it holds plus every other asset. So how much of Apple's worth is in oversea cash? 216/594 = 0.363636. Applying this proportion to the share price, you get 0.363636 * $110 = $40. Meaning that if you split Apple in 5.4 billion shares, each share of that would be entitled to $40 just from the oversea cash itself. Obviously this is a gross simplification, but it's a quick way to get some idea of how much of Apple's value is from its cash holding.